# How to Check null condition in Data weaver : Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

Here is my xml, in that first I need to check 'RecordsEntries' should not be 'null', then RecordEntry shouldn't be `null` followed by mapping code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Records>
  <storenumber />
  <calculated>false</calculated>
  <subTotal>12</subTotal>
 <RecordsEntries>
   <RecordEntry>
     <deliverycharge>30.0</deliverycharge>
     <entryNumber>8</entryNumber>
     <Value>true</Value>
  </RecordEntry>
  <RecordEntry>
    <deliverycharge>20.0</deliverycharge>
    <entryNumber>7</entryNumber>
    <Value>false</Value>
  </RecordEntry>
</RecordsEntries>
 <RecordsEntries>
    <RecordEntry>
      <deliverycharge>30.0</deliverycharge>
      <entryNumber>8</entryNumber>
      <Value>false</Value>
    </RecordEntry>
 </RecordsEntries>
</Records>
```

Tried multiple scenario's also used `when` condition checking but somewhere missing parenthesis or correct format

```
    orders: {
    order: {
  StoreID: payload.Records.storenumber,
  Total: payload.Records.calculated,
 (( payload.Records.RecordsEntries.*RecordEntry ) map {
    IndividualEntry: {
    Number:$.entryNumber,
    DeliverCharge:$.deliverycharge
    }
  } when ( payload.Records.RecordsEntries != null and payload.Records.RecordsEntries.*RecordEntry !=null))}
}
```

getting error like missing `)`. Tried other way around by checking the null condition directly inside the first loop got error like "Cannot coerce array to an boolean". Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can instead do

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml
---
orders: {
  order: {
  StoreID: payload.Records.storenumber,
  Total: payload.calculated,
 ((payload.Records.*RecordsEntries.*RecordEntry default []) map {
      IndividualEntry: {
        Number:$.entryNumber,
        DeliverCharge:$.deliverycharge
      }
    })
  }
}
```

DataWeave is "null-safe" for querying values like in `payload.Records.*RecordsEntries.*RecordEntry`, but an error will be thrown when trying to operate with a null (e.g. `null map {}`).

The `default` operator replaces the value to its left, if it's `null`, with the one on the right.

Also you were missing an `*`. You need to use it in xml whenever you want all the repetitive elements that match.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip a particular field assignment in dataweave based on the null or blank , below mentioned script can be used.

payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> { Name: payload01.Name, (LastName: payload01.LastName) when payload01.LastName !=null and payload01.LastName !='' })

This will skip the field mapping for Name , if the name field is coming as null or blank in the incoming payload.

Comment: you can not use when without otherwise

Comment: In the above mentioned syntax i m skipping the field assignment for lastname when the value in the input side  is null. In this case when can be used without otherwise. I have used this many times.